# How to get all possible shuffle combinations using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array of length `N` containing `X` ones and `N-X` zeroes. I want to generate all possible shuffle combinations of my array.

For example, when `N` is 5 and `X` is 2, I need the following combinations,

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Is there any straight forward way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinations are implemented in the Python standard library, in `itertools`. It picks `X` elements from a list of `N`, so you can let it pick indices and set those to `1`:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

N = 5
X = 2

for combination in combinations(range(N), X):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    arr[list(combination)] = 1
    print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized one with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) -

```
from itertools import combinations

def combs(N, X):
    idx = np.array(list(combinations(range(N), X)))
    n = len(idx)
    out = np.zeros((n,N), dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(n)[:,None],idx] = 1
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [57]: combs(N=5, X=2)
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

In [58]: combs(N=5, X=3)
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [59]: combs(N=5, X=4)
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```