# Make a bruteforce with combinations of a given size only

Tags: python

Maybe the title isn't clear, so let me explain myself.

Let's say I've got a string : "1234567890"

And I want to bruteforce it with a particularity: every combination must be 6 characters long, no less, no more. I already got an itertools example of a complete bruteforce (with alphabet, numbers and symbols) which gives me all values with lengths from 1 to 6, but I don't want that...

Here it is btw :

```py
from itertools import chain, product
def bruteforce(charset, maxlength):
    file = open("test.txt", "w")
    return (''.join(candidate)
        for candidate in chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat=i)
        for i in range(1, maxlength + 1)))
var = str((list(bruteforce("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ²&é(-è_çà)=^$*ù,;:!<1234567890°+¨£µ%?./§>~{[|`\^@]}¤€ .", 6))))
file.write(var)
file.close()
print("Done")
```

So do you know a way to do this, maybe with numpy? I already thought of doing a "classic" bruteforce and then with a for loop, deleting every element with len(element)<6, but it takes so much time and it's really not optimized.

I saw that also : [How to get all possible shuffle combinations using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538848/how-to-get-all-possible-shuffle-combinations-using-numpy)
But it seems to only take 2 numbers, 0 or 1, and not 10 numbers like I would like. I don't really know numpy, so maybe there is a way to adapt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) is just for that:

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable
>   allowing individual elements to be repeated more than once.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

chars = "1234567890"

for candidate in combinations_with_replacement(chars, r=6):
    print(''.join(candidate))
```

Output:

```
111111
111112
111113
111114
111115
111116
111117
111118
111119
111110
111122
111123
111124
111125
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, you need itertools.permutations or itertools.combinations. Here's an example:

```py
from itertools import permutations #or combinations
def bruteforce(charset, maxlength):
    return (''.join(candidate) for candidate in permutations(charset, maxlength))
#or return (''.join(candidate) for candidate in combinations(charset, maxlength))
```